# Digital to analoge voltage regulator

Tags: digital-logic, analog, electronic-load

I am a complete beginner on electronics. I am trying to make  device to control the voltage output according to a digital input. So basically what I need to make is to continuously increase the voltage output when the digital input is 1 (5v). When the input is 0 continuous process should be stopped. 
     Thank You!

Comment: So when the output reaches 5V it will stay at that level forever?

Comment: I think what you want is called a digital potentiometer. (If you are new you might try playing with a analog pot first.)

Comment: Yes there are digital pots available which notch up or down based on input signal. Another thing you could do is use a diode, resistor, and capacitor, so that when you turn on the 5V signal, current flows through the diode and resistor to charge the cap. But when set to 0, the diode prevents the cap from discharging. This will not linearly increase voltage, but it will be continuous. What is this for?